# How do you make Facebook Messenger bot broadcast message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm facing the problems while making Messenger bot broadcast message. I can make it broadcast at first, but I find that when the bot have to send message to a big amount of users (around 100-200 users). It proceed very slow and some users don't get the message.

I'd like to ask you guys that:

1. How do you write code to make bot do broadcast? For me, I just put sendTextMessage it the loop which run all page-scoped ID of users. As far as I know, Facebook don't provide specific broadcast or batch sending command right?
2. According to documentation, Send API do have its limit, but no number specified. It say that 'Messenger Platform supports a high rate of calls to the Send API'. I'd like to know how high is 'high rate' ?

Comment: 1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/ 2. If they would want to give you more specific info on this, they probably would have done so right there already.

Comment: Thanks for info about batch request! I'm looking into it.

Comment: Were you able to make it work?

Comment: @sigmus Yes, it works.

But only works well with limited amount of users. I currently have around 6k user IDs to send message to. I can't send all batches at once because of batch request rate limit. So, I workaround by add some delay between each batch but it takes time to do all the request and some users don't get message. If more delay added it might work better, but my use case is to broadcast in short time so still looking into this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @astider. Just to have an idea, what's the batch size you usually do and what's the average delay between?

Comment: 50 requests per batch (max) with 100 ms delay before the next batch is sent

Answer (score 1):

Facebook just updated its Messenger Platform yesterday (7 Nov).
It's now support Broadcast API (beta) and custom label for targeting recipient. Looks interesting.

https://messenger.fb.com/blog/2-2-release/